# Is there any CMS/tool which can be linked with github/bitbucket?

Tags: web-applications, github, content-management-system, repository

I need a simple web based tool/CMS/app which could be linked to some repository hosting. It is something like Cloud9 IDE, but not for developers but for laymans.

When a user edits a file (say a .txt or a markdown file), it should be version the file with new commit on github ( or any other repository service )- same way as in Cloud9 IDE.

In simple word - it's like Github for Mac ( or now Windows), but web based and for general users not strictly for developers.

Comment: "When a user edits a markdown file, it should backup to github [..]" Sounds like nearly every git-gui implementation (e.g. egit for eclipse) to me :?

Comment: Yes you are right. But that's for developers. I need something similar for users.

Comment: -1. do not use tag 'tools' see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/tools/info

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for pointing it out. But why is that tag is allowed to use at first place when it was cleaned and people who use it are downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to edit files and make a new commit everytime someone edits it, create a repository on GitHub. There's an 'Edit this file' button on every file and it uses the Cloud9 Editor Ace. That's the easiest thing you get, because it will auto-commit and auto-push every time you save.

Otherwise: what's wrong with Cloud9? It's not just for developers, everyone can use it. You just might have to create a cheat sheat for using git :-)